# Making a chess multiplayer game

Tags: vb.net, chess

I am trying to make a Chess multiplayer game in Visual Basic. Its a two player which will be played in a normal way and not even over LAN.
So far, I am done designing the board.

My logic is:
First, on clicking any square, the click event handler will check whether a piece resides on that square. If not, then it checks if a piece is to be moved to that square. If both are negative, then it does nothing.

Now, the problem with this is, how do I code the click events? Also, I have represented the board using a 2dimensional array. But how do I update the positions after every move? And how do I check whether legal move is being executed? One more thing I want to add is whenever a piece is clicked, the possible legal squares should be highlighted.

For this, what I did was, for every click event on any square it checked if there was a piece. If there was a piece, then it highlighted all possible moves for that piece using If-Else-If logic, but it turned out to be too cumbersome and too long. And another problem which arose was, how do I know that if the user clicks an empty square to move the piece there?

Please help me.

Comment: Please clarify the language you are using. You tagged 'VBA', but the question only mentions "Visual Basic". If it is VB and not VBA, are we talking VB6 or VB.NET?

Comment: I meant VB.Net. I think it must have been a mistake on my part on tagging it VBA. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But how do I update the positions after every move?"

**When the piece is about to be moved:**

Check if the piece can move like that. (Like bishop can only move diagonally)

Check that your teams piece is not on the position your about to move.

Make a second array where the move is already happened.

Check if the move was legal. (Its your turn but the your king is kill-able with one move)

**To check this you need:**

To get your kings position

And then look up all the possible moves for the opponent

check if a move can land on your kings position.

Comment: I created an array called position which stores the position of the pieces in the starting position. But how do I update it afterwards? Actually, I am getting the logic but I am having problems with the real implementation.

Comment: If move is legit: Save the contents of the current position in a variable, Delete the contents of the current position and copy the content of the variable to the new position.

Comment: But how do I check if its a legal move? Can you give me code for that?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not really a good fit for Stack Overflow, but I will give you a pointer:

You need to create a class called `ChessPiece`

This will have properties like `IsWhite` and `LocationX` and `LocationY` that stores its current position on the board and PieceType which will be an enumeration like this:

```
Public Enum ChessPieceType
    King
    Queen
    Bishop
    Pawn
    'etc
End Enum
```

You need to create some sort of array of these classes so that you have one for each piece on your board and you can set these positions manaully when the game starts.

When the user attempts to move a piece you check the PieceType enumeration to make sure that type of chess piece can actually move there, then check there isn't one of their own pieces on that square etc etc.